# How to block ip on docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables, docker-swarm

I have a docker machine. There are lots of centos containers on the docker. I wanna block an ip from iptables (on the docker machine ). Then, the centos containers will be blocked.

I try these but don't work

`iptables -A DOCKER-USER -s 192.168.0.210 -j DROP`

and

`iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.210 -j REJECT`

how can I resolve this problem?